# OptaPlanner, force PlanningVariable to be filled in sequence of a range

Tags: optaplanner

Want to sequence a set of tasks with some rules. Each task has an index (the PlanningVariable) to indicate its sequence, its range is from 1 to n. One rule needs to minimize the sum of a shadow variable of all tasks, and it's meaningful only when the sum is calculated from index 1 consecutively to a larger number, say from 1 to 5. It's useless to sum say 2,4,8. Question: Is there any way to force optaplanner to assign 1 to a task and then 2 and then 3 ... to get potential solutions? no waste in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at **the task assigning example** in optaplanner-examples (sources are in zip download in green button on optaplanner.org). [See this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksXjQ851RAU)

It uses a `CHAINED` variable to assign tasks to a (linked) list basically. Then use a `@CustomShadowVariable` to calculate the `index` in that chain for each `Task`.

In a future version of optaplanner, we'll support an `Employee` having a `List<Task>` and a `Task` having a `@IndexShadowVariable`, which will be a much simplier model. But meanwhile you'll have to work with the chained var approach.